# Using IF, AND, and OR statements to not repeat code in Excel

Tags: python, excel, vba

I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to use IF statements in excel. I know what I want my code to look like if it was say, Python, but I'm struggling with it in excel.

Heres the code I have in excel, and it works and does what I want:

```
=IFS((AND(B4="Fall", C4="Triple")), 2190, (AND(B4="Fall", C4="Double")), 2731, (AND(B4="Fall", C4="Single")), 3175,
 AND(B4="Winter", C4="Triple"), 1902,  AND(B4="Winter", C4="Double"), 2372,  AND(B4="Winter", C4="Single"), 2757,
  AND(B4="Spring", C4="Triple"), 1671, AND(B4="Spring", C4="Double"), 2084, AND(B4="Spring", C4="Single"), 2423,
 ISBLANK(B4), "Pick A quarter", ISBLANK(C4), "Pick A dorm style")
```

As you can see, There is lots of stuff that is repeated and is unnecessary. It makes it hard to read, and long to type. Especially since I have to do essentially the same thing with very slight changes to the second parameter in the AND() statements and the results.

Here is what I would like the code to be equivalent to.

```
B4 = "Fall"
C4 = "Double"

if (B4=="Fall"):
    if (C4 == "Triple"):
        print(2190)
    if (C4 == "Double"):
        print(2731)
    if (C4 == "Single"):
        print(3175)
elif (B4 == "Winter"):
    if (C4 == "Triple"):
        print(1902)
    if (C4 == "Double"):
        print(2372)
    if (C4 == "Single"):
        print(2757)
elif (B4 == "Spring"):
    if (C4 == "Triple"):
        print(1671)
    if (C4 == "Double"):
        print(2084)
    if (C4 == "Single"):
        print(2423)
else:
    print("...")
```

Now admittedly, this code still isn't great and it seems like there would be a much better, shorter more efficient way to write this out. But it gets the point across. (If there was a way to create this in python and change excel cells from python code, that'd be cool to). Anyone have some ideas?

Comment: Maybe xlWings for Python. For VBA look at Select Case and If ElseIf.

Comment: @QHarr is VBA excels formula language? And I'll checkout xlWings. Thanks.

Comment: VBA is the programming language to use in the IDE for MS Excel, Access....

Comment: @Brystephor Do you intend to use VBA to solve this problem or do you want to use xlWings?

Comment: @Brystephor - VBA is a variant of the Visual Basic language used for automating Office applications. You can write a function in VBA within the workbook and call it from a formula. I'll add an example as an answer if that's the direction you'd like to try. I personally prefer Axel's answer though.

Comment: @Prasanna I was trying to use VBA, the language is easy to read and implement but I do not like having to click the button as this isn't meant to be interactive. It's meant to just list out straight data and facts without more then selecting from three drop downs to compare different situations. I looked into xlWings, but as of now, I will stick to Excel since there will not be much more complex equations/functions.

Comment: You don't need to click (or have) a button to call a VBA function from a formula. The formula will re-calculate when its dependencies change and will call the function and return the result.

Comment: If you want to take the VBA route, stick with @andrew response. If your actual data is much larger than the example you have given here, prefer to stick with the `index` & `match` functions

Comment: @Prasanna I ended up sticking with `index` and `match` as my data set is going to be growing over time but will be able to stay close to the same structure, just adding more rows, possibly more columns eventually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common `Excel`solution is having a helper table and using `INDEX` - `MATCH`.

Example:

[image]

Formula in `B5`:

```
=INDEX($F$3:$H$5,MATCH(B4,$E$3:$E$5,0),MATCH(C4,$F$2:$H$2,0))
```

The helper table could be on a separate sheet which could be hidden. So it would be not visible.

Comment: I'll look this up and look into it, this is so much cleaner then what I have. Could you explain to me what is going on here? For example, why the '$'?

Is this saying The table to take values from is from F3 to H5, then match the input in B4 with what's in cells E3 to E5. Then do that again with input from C4, look through row F2 to H2, and where the row & column intersect, put that value in the selected cell?

Comment: @Brystephor: Your questions are about very basic `Excel` knowledge. Try googling for a `Excel` tutorial. Search keywords: "Excel tutorial INDEX MATCH".

Answer (score 4):

You can call a VBA function that resides within the workbook from within a formula, passing the two input cells as parameters.

Add a Module in the VBA IDE with the following code:

```
Function GetRate(season As String, size As String)
    If season = "Fall" Then
        If size = "Triple" Then
            GetRate = 2190
        ElseIf size = "Double" Then
            GetRate = 2731
        ElseIf size = "Single" Then
            GetRate = 3175
        End If
    ElseIf season = "Winter" Then
        If size = "Triple" Then
            GetRate = 1902
        ElseIf size = "Double" Then
            GetRate = 2372
        ElseIf size = "Single" Then
            GetRate = 2757
        End If
    ElseIf season = "Spring" Then
        If size = "Triple" Then
            GetRate = 1671
        ElseIf size = "Double" Then
            GetRate = 2084
        ElseIf size = "Single" Then
            GetRate = 2423
        End If
    Else
        GetRate = "..."
    End If
End Function
```

Note: I literally just quickly translated your python code to VBA. I won't delve into the quality of said code since it seems out of scope for this question. (It's not bad as such but there could be improvements.)

Call the function in a cell formula and pass two cell references as parameters:

`=GetRate(A1, B1)`

The workbook must be saved with the file type "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm)". It will warn you if you don't, and you will lose the module and code if you ignore the warning and save as a normal .XLS file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about excel, but this Python code:

```
if (B4=="Fall"):
    if (C4 == "Triple"):
        print(2190)
    if (C4 == "Double"):
        print(2731)
    if (C4 == "Single"):
        print(3175)
elif (B4 == "Winter"):
    if (C4 == "Triple"):
        print(1902)
    if (C4 == "Double"):
        print(2372)
    if (C4 == "Single"):
        print(2757)
elif (B4 == "Spring"):
    if (C4 == "Triple"):
        print(1671)
    if (C4 == "Double"):
        print(2084)
    if (C4 == "Single"):
        print(2423)
else:
    print("...")
```

does approximately the same as this nicer Python code:

```
print {
    ("Fall", "Triple"): 2190,
    ("Fall", "Double"): 2731,
    ("Fall", "Single"): 3175,
    ("Winter", "Triple"): 1902,
    ("Winter", "Double"): 2372,
    ("Winter", "Single"): 2757,
    ("Spring", "Triple"): 1671,
    ("Spring", "Double"): 2084,
    ("Spring", "Single"): 2423,
}.get((B4, C4), '...')
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the case statement could be effective...

Here is a link to how it works.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_switch_statement.htm

Cheers.

Comment: Providing only a link as an answer is not encouraged on stack overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for guidelines about giving quality answers.